# chmod + silent mode + how force exit code 0 in spite of error

Tags: shell, shell-script, chmod, error-handling

Is it possible execute chmod and ignore error from command

Example ( remark file.txt not exsist to show the example )

When I type

```
chmod 777 file.txt
```

I get error on the output

```
  chmod: cannot access file.txt : no such file or directory
```

So I add the-f flag to the command as the following: ( file.txt not exist in order to show the case )

```
  chmod -f 777 file.txt
  echo $?
  1
```

But from the example chmod return 1

Please advice how to force the chmod command to give exit code 0 in spite of error

Comment: Why is that upvoted? Suppress any unwanted output with `2>/dev/null` and use `set -e` in scripts.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

> Please advice how to force the chmod command to give exit code 0 in
>   spite of error

```
chmod -f 777 file.txt || :
```

This would execute `:`, i.e. the null command, if `chmod` fails.  Since the null command does nothing but always succeeds, you would see an exit code of 0.

Comment: Equivalent, but more readable for a casual user is to use `chmod -f 777 file.txt || true`

Comment: @orion Depends.  If one is familiar, then `:` seems equally readable.

Comment: But if we write more readable code that the noobs can read, how will we keep our jobs?

Comment: chef developer here, just dropping some key words to help out others that have encountered the same issue I have. shell_out!(cmd+'|| true') is a lifesaver when you're trying to be idempotent with installations and need to ignore shell_out! compile errors.

Answer (score 77):

`chmod -f 777 file.txt || true`

As it's an OR, if one of the statements returns true, then the the return is true. This results in an exit status of zero.

Comment: I added this answer as an alternative to promote the practice writing readable code.

Comment: The right branch of `||` won't get executed if `chmod` is successful... not that it makes much of a computational difference here.

Comment: Thank you for that. I can't believe I messed that up. :) Edited with the correction.

Answer (score 9):

I always loved

```
 chmod -f 777 file.txt || exit 0
```

Comment: This makes the script stop when chmod was unsuccessful. The question was to make the script continue running when there was a problem with it (ignore error).